# p/Invoke delegate causes Unity to crash on iOS

Tags: ios, delegates, unity-game-engine, pinvoke, aot

I make a ios plugin in unity

//c code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    typedef int (*callback_t) (int a, int b);
    static callback_t my_callback;

    void RegisterCallback (callback_t cb)
    {
        my_callback = cb;
    }

    int InvokeManagedCode (int a, int b)
    {
        if (my_callback == NULL){
         printf ("Managed code has not initialized this library yet");
         abort ();
         }
        return (*my_callback) (a, b);
    }
```

//C# in unity

```
    public class PluginImport : MonoBehaviour {

     delegate int MyCallback1 (int a, int b);

     [DllImport ("__Internal")]
     extern static void RegisterCallback (MyCallback1 callback1);

 [DllImport ("__Internal")]
     extern static int InvokeManagedCode (int a, int b);

     void Start () {

     RegisterCallback(Add); //register call back

  int i=InvokeManagedCode(44,4);
  Debug.Log("in ios?"+i);

     }

     static int Add (int a, int b) { return a + b; } //my delegate in C#
     static int Sub (int a, int b) { return a - b; }

    }
```

the run good on unity,but on ios throw a error
ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper native-to-managed) PluginImport:Add (int,int)' while running with --aot-only.

at (wrapper managed-to-native) PluginImport:RegisterCallback (PluginImport/MyCallback1)
  at PluginImport.Start () [0x00000] in :0

(Filename:  Line: -1)
how to do reverse native callbacks inside Unity on ios device? 
please help me。

Comment: I got a selution   [MonoPInvokeCallbackAttribute(typeof(MyCallback1))]
             static int Add (int a, int b) { return a + b; }               it work